# Multiple transformers to generate high voltage

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I'm trying to generate high voltage from a 5 volt battery source. 
Currently I have some normal transformers from my old devices that I think can transform 5V to 220V. If I connect several of these transformers together can I reach very high voltage?  For example: 5V * 44 = 220V, and then 220V * 44 = 9680V?

[image: DC converter]

Comment: You mean to connect primaries in parallel and secondaries in series?. In any case, each transformer rated with a maximum voltage to avoid arcs between layers of wounds. Is your transformer rated as such?

Comment: It can't easily be done with the yellow type transformer you show in your image. What do you need 10kV for anyway, maybe there is a more viable solution.

Comment: Please do not do this with the transformer shown, the terminals are too close together for a 10,000 volt application! You may injure yourself or start a fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example , 5v * 44 = 220v , and then 220v * 44 = 9680v

Paraphrasing the above quote: Using two cascaded transformers,  the first produces 220V and this feeds into the second that magnifies this by a further 44 times to get 9680 V

It won't work so don't even bother trying it. There are two reasons: -

- The magnetic core of the 2nd transformer will heavily saturate and fry (if enough energy could be supplied by the 1st transformer)
- The breakdown voltage between consecutive turns (and layers) of a winding intended for 220 VAC might be 1500 V but certainly won't be ~10kV.

Enough said.